# Debugging Jasmine Specs using VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, visual-studio-code

Is there any way I can debug my code (Node.js) and jasmine tests through VS Code?
I have a spec in which I'm creating a spy, but my assertion that the spy should be called is returning false, even though when I invoke the function it calls within the spec manually it does run in to that code.

I've tried F5'ing the application to attach a debugger to the application which starts up an express server (that i've been using for testing until now) and then simply running `jasmine` from the command prompt, but no breakpoints are hit.

As an example of what I'm doing in the spec, I'm setting up the spy as follows:

```
var response = {
            tell: function(value) {
                console.log("inside response.tell spy");
            }
        };
spyOn(response, "tell");
```

Invoking my function, passing in the response object and then adding my expectation:

```
expect(response.tell).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But the expectation fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can run the `jasmine.js` file via node and pass `JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH` as an environment variable.

`JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH="test/jasmine.json" node --debug-brk --no-lazy node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine.js`